Am I correct in understanding that "hocher la tête" means both to "nod" and to "shake" one's head?
I've been reading a book and realized that hocher la tête is being used to describe both someone nodding and someone shaking their head. Is this one of those phrases that's entirely dependent on context for its meaning? So for instance a passage like this:

Je lui ai demandé s'il voudrait nous accompagner. Il a hoché la tête.

--is completely ambiguous, and you have no idea if the person being asked is signalling yes or no. Is that right?

You are right as confirmed by A. − 1. in the TLF

A dictionary would give you the translation into English, but I expect a French dictionary would be enough.

That is just so strange to me as an English speaker. Nodding and shaking your head are so common and so opposite that I just expected them to each have their own separate term. It's as though good and bad were the same word.

@temporary_user_name: It's not so different from the verb "gesture" in English. "He gestured to me to stop/go/stand up/sit down/come over/stay away". We don't have separate words for most gestures (giving somebody the finger being one of a few exceptions).

Excellent conceptual analogy Peter, you make a good point. Thanks.


(TLFi) A. − Usuel.
1. Secouer (la tête, le menton) de droite à gauche ou de haut en bas pour exprimer des sentiments divers, voire opposés, et interprétés d'après la mimique qui accompagne ce mouvement.
• Hocher la tête d'un air de doute, en signe d'approbation, d'incrédulité, de regret.

Les deux ruraux hochaient la tête en signe de refus (Maupass., Contes et nouv., t. 1, Champs, 1882, p. 78).
Jerphanion écoutait sans interrompre, hochant la tête d'un air de compréhension sympathique (Romains, Hommes bonne vol., 1938, p. 124).
M. Rambout hocha la tête; mais je ne sus pas si c'était en signe d'incrédulité ou d'admiration (Bosco, Mas Théot., 1945, p. 222)
Moins de trois ans après, non pas en enfance, mais un peu ramollie, je devais la voir [Mme de Forcheville] à une soirée donnée par Gilberte, et devenue incapable de cacher sous un masque immobile ce qu'elle pensait (pensait est beaucoup dire), ce qu'elle éprouvait, hochant la tête, serrant la bouche, secouant les épaules à chaque impression qu'elle ressentait... Proust, Temps retr., 1922, p. 951.


This verb means only "to shake" when what is shaken is the head; this gesture is not used only for acquiescence/agreement/acceptation/approbation/… or denial/refusal/… but also when certain impressions are being communicated. In order to eliminate any ambiguity, it is necessary to add some details. The examples show that; in particular the third one shows that short of any details it is not possible to know what the person's feelings or intentions are.
Those details are introduced as prepositional phrases and adverbs, and as descriptions of attitudes that give away the person's feelings.
Prepositional phrases and adverbs

pour dire/exprimer/montrer/signifier/… approbation/refus/dégout/…
en signe de refus/approbation/assentiment…
négativement
positivement
…

Descriptions of attitudes

avec un air de ne pas vouloir/croire/…
en écarquillant les yeux pour montrer son horreur
…

Interesting facts derived from comments (user XouDo)
(Est-ce que la définition TLFI est un peu datée ? De nos jours, il me semble que hocher la tête est surtout utiliser pour agiter la tête de haut en bas (pour acquiscer). Pour "de droite à gauche", on utilise plutôt "faire non de la tête", non ? – XouDo)
Je suis d'accord avec le fait que « hocher » est plutôt un mot de la littérature, mais si on a à demander à quelqu'un la raison de ses mouvements avec la tête dans une conversation, je crois aussi qu'il n'y aurait pas de meilleure option (« remuer » ne semble pas convenir au dialogue, en cela que c'est un verbe qui pourrait insinuer peut-être qu'on interprète le mouvement comme un fait étranger à la conversation (tic nerveux, ou autre problème de santé)).
// Je crois  que dans la langue parlée on n'emploie comparativement que très peu « hocher » ; cet ngram, « fit non de la tête,dit non en hochant la,dit non d'un hochement », montre que dans la langue imprimée « faire non de la tête » est la seule option choisie, ce que j'apprends.

Bien que ce soit une expression qui ait fait son apparition au moins en 1891, elle semble véritablement être une réalité  du 20e siècle et surtout du 21e (fit non de la tête). Elle a pris un essor vertigineux au début du siècle.
// Il me semble que non, la définition serait toujours exacte, mais légèrement incomplète si on se réfère au Wiktionnaire qui avance un exemple de 1911 où il n'est plus question de la tête (hocher, Wiktionnaire). On peut remarquer que tous les exemples du Wiktionnaire hormis celui qui ne concerne pas la tête, le hochement n'est associé à rien en particulier.

Est-ce que la définition TLFI est un peu datée ? De nos jours, il me semble que hocher la tête est surtout utiliser pour agiter la tête de haut en bas (pour acquiscer). Pour "de droite à gauche", on utilise plutôt "faire non de la tête", non ?

@XouDo Réponse à votre commentaire à la fin du texte de ma réponse au PO.

@XouDo Le Robert, plus récent, est en phase avec le TLF. « de haut en bas pour signifier « oui », de droite à gauche pour signifier « non » »
